# Span a Dojo tabcontainer inside contentpane (href)

Tags: javascript, dojo, href, contentpane

I have a dojo `ContentPane` on my main page. I use the `href` attribute (as an iframe alternative) of it to load a different php file, depending on some data on the main page. This other php file contains the `TabContainer`.  
My problem is that the TabContainer shows only when I specify the height and width in `pixels`. I want to set the height and width in `percentages`. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

**Main Page:**

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="href:'myTabs.php', splitter:false" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
```

**myTabs.html:**

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width:500px;height:600px;">
...
</div
```